# Make section in infopath that is visible to only user present in other shairpoint list

Tags: infopath

I am stuck  with a scenario on Shairpoint.

i have a infopath form in which there is a section which i want to make visible to only people whose email id is present in another shairpoint list any person not present in that list if access the form   he will not be able to see that section.

Kindly guide me with what condition and rules i can achieve this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to achieve that with the rules and conditions. You could try to to connect that list as a secondary data source and then try to use it in the condition. But I would switch to IP form with code behind (if you are on prem) and do what you need in C#, the logic will be much clearer in code than through rules.